# How to implement a view in Android that behaves like a HTML block with property "float:left"?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

In this example the blocks #4 and #6 are moved to the next line because there isn't enough space for them on the current line. It is basically the same behaviour as a block element in HTML with CSS properties like "display: block; float: left;". Let's take the situation where I want to place images on the screen in this fashion. How to implement this?

Comment: I'd be interested to see a positive answer to this. To my knowledge I can't see how you would. 

You could put them in their own linear layouts 

    (1, 2, 3) 
    (4, 5) 
    (6) 

This would force them on their own rows, but I don't know how to make them adjust rows depending on the width.

Comment: I haven't done to much in android especially as of late but I believe `wrap-content` is what your looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridLayout` comes closest, but it resizes its children to equal sizes, so it wouldn't work for the example image you've shown. If you're just talking about a consistent grid of images/buttons/whatever, it's perfect for that.

For the other, there is a third party solution: [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout).

It's based on a `LinearLayout`, so you just set it to horizontal orientation and add all the elements you like. It will flow to the next line when it should, and no need to implement measuring/adjusting on your own.

Note: I haven't tested this in a while, so I'm not sure how it behaves on the newest APIs. The last time I used it was for a Gingerbread app, and it worked fine at that point.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly there is a thing called a gridlayout view, I think this is what you are looking for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

*EDIT*: There is also compatibility support for this as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So the idea is to precalculate width for each image and programmatically place them on the grid one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout` and use the [`android:layout_toRightOf`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_toRightOf) attribute, to simulate this.

Regarding wrapping around behavior you may need to extend the `View` class for the children and particularly the [`onLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) function to programmatically toggle whether it is to `theRightOf` or `below` its preceding element.

Maybe something like this, *psedo* :

```
protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
   if (right < 0) {
       # toggle to below and maybe parent left
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! But one question: what happens when an element is very close to the right edge? If I put another image to the right of it - is it just going to the next line?

Comment: @x2bool I'm not sure, you could test it out. However read the edit I made about how you would do it.