# Add view horizontaly and verticaly in LinearLayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-linearlayout

I want to add dynamic view into a Horizontal LinearLayout. But my issue is if there is no space at Horizontal it should automatically placed on vertically.

My Image

[image]

My Expected Result

[image]

My Codes are

```
    for (int j = 0; j < jobDet.getKeywords().length; j++) {

               RelativeLayout tr_head = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tag_lay, null);

               TextView label_date = (TextView) tr_head.findViewById(R.id.tag_name);
               label_date.setText(jobDet.getKeywords()[j]);

               keywordL.addView(tr_head, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

           }
```

My "tag_lay.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="30dp"
             android:id="@+id/tag_name"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:paddingRight="10dp"
             android:background="@drawable/round_edit_box"
             android:text="     PHP     "
             android:gravity="center"
             android:lines="1"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use GridLayout instead of LinearLayout

Comment: the width of view is not same  
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwEdSSxsfhd7OFpmTGdnWlNBUDg

Comment: can show how it should look like?

Comment: My expected Layout: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwEdSSxsfhd7OFpmTGdnWlNBUDg

Comment: there is a similar question and as SaravInfern and Onkar Nene referred you could use GridLayout please take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080635/how-to-implement-a-view-in-android-that-behaves-like-a-html-block-with-property

Comment: check my complete answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59430605/2326640 that's what you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not do that with single `LinearLayout` because it has either `VERTICAL` or `HORIZONTAL` orientation. I would suggest you to take a look at google's [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). Its a library which provides a layout where you can achieve similar view. You can add this library by adding below line to your app level gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.1.3'
```

You can change the `keywordL` to `FlexboxLayout` from `LinearLayout`. A sample code for container layout can be something like below:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/flexbox_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:alignContent="flex_start"
         app:alignItems="flex_start"
         app:flexWrap="wrap"/>
```

You can change the value of `alignContent`, `alignItems` and `flexWrap` according to your requirement. Although this should work because it is working for me. While adding the childs you can do something like below:

```
for (int j = 0; j < jobDet.getKeywords().length; j++) {

           RelativeLayout tr_head = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tag_lay, keywordL, false );

           TextView label_date = (TextView) tr_head.findViewById(R.id.tag_name);
           label_date.setText(jobDet.getKeywords()[j]);
           keywordL.addView(tr_head);
       }
```

Please let me know if you have trouble implementing.

Comment: then please accept the answer, it might help others.